# Multiple hosted services of the same type with different configurations?

Tags: asp.net, .net, background-service, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a service I am trying to implement for an ASP.NET application, `SomeService` which is an implementation of `BackgroundService` responsible for consuming messages off of a message queue. There are several different queues that I would like to consume at the same time, but with different delays. For example:

```
[
    {
        "queueName": "queue1",
        "interval": 5
    },
    {
        "queueName": "queue2",
        "interval": 10
    }
]
```

I would like to be able to register two instances of `someService`, one for `queue1` and one for `queue2`

Is it possible to do something like
`configurations.ForEach(x=> services.AddHostedService<SomeService>(x));`
with each instance of the service running with its own configuration?